# Problem with My Acer D250 Netbook and WIFI Adapter in Lubuntu 12.10

Tags: wireless, 12.10, lubuntu, adapter

Hi I am having a problem after a clean installation of Lubuntu 12.10

AFter the initial installation, my wifi adapter cannot function and thus offer me wifi connnectivity. I downloaded all the updates but still nothing. I am using Ubuntu after the 10.x version where I could locate the device manager and update everything needed. In 12.10 version, I can;t find the device manager at all.

To sum up let me tell you that ALL the above happened at exactly the same way during my Ubuntu 12.10 installation some weeks ago. (I decided to turn it into Lubuntu for faster operation).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the "restricted drivers" window, that one has been moved since 12.10

It is now located under Software Sources under the tab "extra drives"